# Implicit conversion of date field in a pl/sql trigger?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to develop a trigger in PL/SQL (Oracle) `before INSERT`.

In this table there is a column (`cdat`) of type DATE.

Let's say i do `INSERT INTO myTbl (123,'12/05/2011');`

In my trigger the `:NEW.CDAT` is converted in the final date system or it's still a varchar?

Do I need to do a `TO_DATE(:NEW.CDAT)` to get the date value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:NEW.CDAT` will be a date.  The `:new` and `:old` variables in triggers are always the type of the destination field.

---

I wasn't able to find anything in the Oracle documentation that confirms my statement, but I was able to devise some experimental proof:

```
CREATE TABLE test2 (a DATE);

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER bu_test2
   BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
   ON test2
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   PROCEDURE type_test(in_type DATE) IS
   BEGIN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('date');
   END;
   PROCEDURE type_test(in_type VARCHAR2) IS
   BEGIN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('varchar2');
   END;
BEGIN
   type_test(:new.a);
END;

INSERT INTO test2
  VALUES   ('24-Mar-2011');
```

Since type_test is overloaded, Oracle will choose which procedure to use based on the type being passed in.  The results of this script are:

```
Table created.
Trigger created.
date
1 row created.
```

Comment: what was the output there? date or varchar2 ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a conversion if your session parameter '**NLS_DATE_FORMAT**' is not '**mm/dd/yyyy**'.

For example:

```
create table    myTbl  (id number, cdat date);
select *
from   nls_session_parameters ns
where  ns.parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';

PARAMETER                    VALUE
-------------------------------------------------------
NLS_DATE_FORMAT              DD-MON-RR
```

In this case, without a to_Date you'll get an error:

```
insert into myTbl
values
    (123, '12/05/2011');

ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

You can change this paramter at session level, system level, etc.

```
zep@dev> alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'mm/dd/yyyy';

Session altered

select *
from   nls_session_parameters ns
where  ns.parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';

PARAMETER                VALUE
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NLS_DATE_FORMAT          mm/dd/yyyy

insert into myTbl
    (id, cdat)
values
        (123, '12/05/2011');

1 row inserted

zep@dev> select *
      2  from   myTbl;

        ID CDAT
---------- -----------
       123 05/12/2011
```

---

**Test on a row level trigger**

```
truncate table Mytbl;
alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-RR';       
create or replace trigger befins_myTbl
    before insert on myTbl
    for each row
declare
begin
    -- demo
    :new.cdat := :new.cdat + numtoyminterval(1,'YEAR');-- (demo trigger add 1 year )
end;

insert into myTbl
(id, cdat)
values
(123, '12/05/2011');
```

**Output**: ORA-01843: **not a valid month**

```
alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'mm/dd/yyyy';

insert into myTbl
    (id, cdat)
values
    (123, '12/05/2011');
commit;

select *
from   myTbl;
```

Output

```
ID         CDAT
---------- -----------
123        12/05/2012
```

Comment: He was asking if he needed to do the conversion in the trigger.  If the string can't be converted, the trigger will not run.

Comment: @Allan Yes, I know, and I have pointed out where it is the problem! 
It isn't a problem related to a trigger, but instead it is related to the insert  statement.